# A question about the use of Sum

Tags: summation

Suppose I have the following formula. It calculates the average value of $n$ evenly spaces numbers on the range from $L$ to $H$.

```
1/n Sum[x, {x, L, H, (H - L)/(n - 1)}]
```

My question is, how can I use Mathematica to compute the average value of the above, when I remove a specific number from the sequence. I am looking for an elegant solution, perhaps one that removes a particular index, or some other method I have not thought about.

Ideally, the solution should allow me to plot the average of the numbers on the Y-axis, and the removed index on the X-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to just manage this as a list:

```
list[l_, h_, n_] := Table[x, {x, l, h, (h-l)/(n-1)}];
ListPlot[Table[Mean[Drop[list[1, 10, 10], {i}]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

> [image: Example Plot of Average vs. Dropped Index]

If you really want to do this with sums, it'd be possible to modify the formula slightly by subtracting off the missing term:

```
1/(n - 1) (Sum[x, {x, l, h, (h - l)/(n - 1)}] - ((h - l)/(n - 1) i + l))
```

> (-l - (i (h - l))/(-1 + n) + (Floor[n] (-h - l + 2 l n + h Floor[n] - l Floor[n]))/(2 (-1 + n)))/(-1 + n)

Plotting this for `h->10`, `l->1`, and `n->10`, over `{i, 0, 9, 1}` provides the same plot as previously shown.

Answer (score 1):

The maths is very simple.  For any list `ls`

```
ls = Range[1, 19];
m = Mean[ls]
(* 10 *)
```

we can "downdate" our estimate of the mean

```
x = 15;
Mean[Complement[ls, {x}]] == Module[{n = Length[ls]}, (n m - x)/(n - 1)]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n_, l_, h_] := Module[{r = Subdivide[l, h, n - 1]},   
   MapIndexed[{#, Mean[Drop[r, #2]]} &, r]]

ListPlot[Callout[#, {##}]& /@ f[6, 11, 21]]
```

[image]